# How does Liskov's Substitution Principle work for classes like Object?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

In short, Liskov's Substitution Principle states that instances of the base (super) class should be completely replaceable with instances its derived (sub) classes without introducing any "breaking code" like throwing new errors, changing the contract of the methods, etc.

This means `java.lang.Object` should be replaceable with instances of any of its subclasses everywhere. However, **every** class is a subtype of Object.

I can instantiate a class say, for example, `NetworkAdapter` and pass it as an Object and according to LSP, I should be able to cast that `Object` instance into a random subclass, say `Foo`? However, `NetworkAdapter` and `Foo` are **completely incompatible** with each other.

```
NetworkAdapter nA = new NetworkAdapter();
Object obj = (Object) nA;   // completely okay and legal
Foo foo = (Foo) obj;   // ??? this would throw ClassCastException!
```

Am I understanding LSP wrong? Or does the structure of the Java language violate LSP in some cases?

Comment: You did not demonstrate "replacing" any object. "Replacing" a superclass object with a subclass object means actually changing the source code. In order to demonstrate the LSP, you should show two versions of your code, before and after the replacement.

Comment: Okay so if I understand correctly, LSP isn't about "casts"? It's about the actual replacement of the instance of the superclass with one of the subclasses' instances and still be valid, right?

Comment: Correct. It's not about casts.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to think about the LSP in terms of casting, it would be concerned with upcasting rather than downcasting.

Can you safely pass `NetworkAdapter` to a method that accepts `Object` or does the subclass violate the contract of the parent? Violations of the `Object` contract would include incorrectly implementing `equals` and `hashCode`.